# How to use Logger in Boilerplatejs

Tags: logging, boilerplatejs

I notice a logger class in the helpers folder, but I don't know how to use it, it driving me crazy, I tried with:

```
var log = new Logger();
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Here is the code in logger.js https://github.com/ectechno/boilerplatejs/blob/master/app/core/helpers/logger.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer:

```
var Logger = new Boiler.Helpers.Logger;
Logger.info('Log working');
```